# Parsing emails and attachments

Tags: c#, email, outlook-addin

I have a requirement to parse email messages and upload the email into DB based on certain filters. I have experience writing outlook add-in and it is possible to do this in client side.

But here i think i need to write some plugin in exchange server and parse the email messages there itself. is my assumption right? if so please point me to some tutorial for writing exchange server plugins.

Comment: Here's a link to a similar situation.  Check it out:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3080035/how-to-parse-e-mail-into-database

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use my [MimeKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MimeKit) library to parse the messages.